# Nesting awk with variable in for loop?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm looking to turn this code into a for loop using awk with variable. It's a program that pulls the numbers under "totalframes", "landing lag", and "notes" for each of a character's aerial moves in Super Smash Bros. Example section of data:

```
    <div class="movecontainer">
        <div class="hitbox">
            Normal<a class="hitboximg" data-featherlight="hitboxes/fox/FoxFAir.gif"></a>
            Landing<a class="hitboximg" data-featherlight="hitboxes/fox/FoxFAirLanding.gif"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="movename">
        Forward Air
        </div>
        <div class="startup">
        7/11/16/21/26
        </div>
        <div class="totalframes">
        43
        </div>
        <div class="landinglag">
        18
        </div>
        <div class="notes">
        Landing hit on frame 1. Autocancels on frame 46 onward
        </div>
        <div class="basedamage">
        1.8/1.2/1.72.7/4.8/2.0
        </div>
        <div class="shieldlag">
        4/4/4/5/12/9
        </div>
        <div class="shieldstun">
        2/2/2/2/3/3
        </div>
        <div class="whichhitbox">
        Last one is landing hitbox
        </div>
        <div class="advantage">
        -14
        </div>
        <div class="activeframes">
        7—8/11—12/16—17/21—22/26—27
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="movecontainer">
        <div class="hitbox">
            <a class="hitboximg" data-featherlight="hitboxes/fox/FoxBAir.gif"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="movename">
        Back Air
        </div>
        <div class="startup">
        9
        </div>
        <div class="totalframes">
        48
        </div>
        <div class="landinglag">
        9
        </div>
        <div class="notes">
        Autocancels on frame 1-6 and 18 onward
        </div>
        <div class="basedamage">
        13.0
        </div>
        <div class="shieldlag">
        9
        </div>
        <div class="shieldstun">
        5
        </div>
        <div class="whichhitbox">
        --
        </div>
        <div class="advantage">
        -4
        </div>
        <div class="activeframes">
        9—11
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="movecontainer">
        <div class="hitbox">
            <a class="hitboximg" data-featherlight="hitboxes/fox/FoxUAir.gif"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="movename">
        Up Air
        </div>
        <div class="startup">
        9/12
        </div>
        <div class="totalframes">
        35
        </div>
        <div class="landinglag">
        13
        </div>
        <div class="notes">
        Autocancels on frame 1-8 and 25 onward
        </div>
        <div class="basedamage">
        5.0/10.0
        </div>
        <div class="shieldlag">
        6/8
        </div>
        <div class="shieldstun">
        3/4
        </div>
        <div class="whichhitbox">
        First/Second
        </div>
        <div class="advantage">
        -10/-9
        </div>
        <div class="activeframes">
        9—10/12—13
        </div>
    </div>
```

Desired output:

```
Forward
43
18
46
Back
48
9
18
Up
35
13
25
Down
49
17
28
Neutral
38
7
32
```

Current solution:

```
echo -n "Character: "
read char

awk '/Forward Air$/{print $1; getline; getline; getline; getline; getline; getline; print $1; getline; getline; getline; print $1; getline; getline; getline; print $0}' data/chars/$char > output.txt

awk '/Back Air$/{print $1; getline; getline; getline; getline; getline; getline; print $1; getline; getline; getline; print $1; getline; getline; getline; print $0}' data/chars/$char >> output.txt

awk '/Up Air$/{print $1; getline; getline; getline; getline; getline; getline; print $1; getline; getline; getline; print $1; getline; getline; getline; print $0}' data/chars/$char >> output.txt

awk '/Down Air$/{print $1; getline; getline; getline; getline; getline; getline; print $1; getline; getline; getline; print $1; getline; getline; getline; print $0}' data/chars/$char >> output.txt

awk '/Neutral Air$/ {print $1; getline; getline; getline; getline; getline; getline; print $1; getline; getline; getline; print $1; getline; getline; getline; print $0}' data/chars/$char >> output.txt

grep -o -E ".{0,3}onward.{0,1}" output.txt > output2.txt

awk '{print $1}' output2.txt > output3.txt
```

The easiest way to simplify would seem to be to create a for loop, (e.g. "For ("Forward Air", "Back Air", "Up Air", "Down Air", "Neutral Air"), execute *awk function*"), but I haven't had any luck finding the correct syntax for this.

The getline spam is clunky, but I'm ignoring that for now because I learned that there are better tools than awk. I mainly just want to turn this into a for loop with awk using variable.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: update the question to include the sample data ... not as an image but as text that you cut-n-paste into the question ... we're not going to expend any effort trying to convert images to textual data we can cut-n-paste into our environments for coding/testing purposes; also, update the question to include the (wrong?) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output (all ouput should correspond with the sample data provided such that if we run your code we can generate the same (wrong?) output

Comment: I _strongly_ recommend using a language that has library support for HTML/XML instead of awk in this case. Something natively aware like XQuery would be ideal, but Python has plenty of choices in its standard-library that will do just as well. Using tools built for plain text introduces fragility: If your whole document were written on just one line, f/e, it would still be the same XML document with the same meaning, but it would completely break any XML-unaware parser. Similarly, XML-unaware tools won't understand comments, DTD processing instructions, etc etc.

Comment: This is not a case for awk. Use a language that has a proper HTML parser. Python, Java, C++, PHP, Perl, you name it, it will have an HTML parser. As you have it written right now, any change in the layout of your HTML that you have to process will break the code.

Comment: If you're ever considering using `getline` please make sure to read and understand http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first. Regarding turning what you have into a loop - it's extremely unlikely that that'd be a good approach.

Comment: Do you REALLY expect to get output for `Down` and `Neutral` moves from that sample input you provided? Please [edit] your question to either explain the algorithm to get that if you do or to fix your example so the input/output are consistent otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xsltproc` instead of `awk`.

This piece of code gives you a first draft of what you try to achieve:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//div[@class = 'movecontainer']">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
        div[@class = 'movename']/child::text())"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><!-- insert new line -->
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
        div[@class = 'totalframes']/child::text())"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><!-- insert new line -->
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
        div[@class = 'landinglag']/child::text())"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><!-- insert new line -->
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
        div[@class = 'notes']/child::text())"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><!-- insert new line -->
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Assuming the stylesheet above is called `prog.xsl` and your input stays in a well formed XML file called `input.xml`, you can launch `xsltproc` as follows:

```sh
xsltproc prog.xsl input.xml
```

It will produce next output that still needs to be fine tuned:

```
Forward Air
43
18
Landing hit on frame 1. Autocancels on frame 46 onward
Back Air
48
9
Autocancels on frame 1-6 and 18 onward
Up Air
35
13
Autocancels on frame 1-8 and 25 onward
```

If this works for you, you have to add code for removing the string "Air" at the end of the `movename` field, and for extracting the number you want from the `note` field.

You could also filter this output through `awk` or `sed` for cleaning it according to your needs, as in:

```
xsltproc prog.xsl input.xml | sed -e '/ Air/s///' -e 's/^.* \([0-9]*\) onward$/\1/'
```

which gives you the output you want.

If you prefer `awk` to `sed`, use next filter on the output of `xsltproc`:

```
xsltproc prog.xsl input.xml | awk '/Air/{print $1; next}/Autocancels/{print $(NF-1); next}1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want with awk:

```
$ awk '
    f { print $(/Autocancels/ ? NF-1 : 1); f=0 }
    /<div class="(movename|totalframes|landinglag|notes)">/ { f=1 }
' file
Forward
43
18
46
Back
48
9
18
Up
35
13
25
```